# HorizontalScrollView and current button

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am building a UI similar the Motorola Music android app(pictured below) where a user can brows through a selection of images each representing something.  I am assuming its using HorizontalScrollView or something similar to let you scroll though your selection.
My questions are, is this the correct UI widget?  If not which is better?  And if it is, how can I see if a certain selection has focus or not?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, since it looks more similar to the analogy of slideshow. 
Looks like it suits your scenario.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Answer (score 2):

The `Gallery` widget is probably better suited for this: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html

You will need to customize it in order to get the desired effects above.

Also check out open source projects like http://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/